# Unicode Z notation brackets

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

I typeset Unicode mathematical symbols using the `unicode-math` and the `fontspec` package.

For the Z notation brackets: ⦇ and ⦈

https://unicodes.smpc.io/%E2%A6%87

and

https://unicodes.smpc.io/%E2%A6%88

this package does not work.

What do you suggest to typeset these symbols?

UPDATE: I used

```
$⦇$ and $⦈$
```

to typeset these symbols. For other Unicode math symbols this worked.

Comment: could you add a few lines of script to explain your issue instead of redirecting us to an external link? nevertheless, the external links tend to die over time.

Comment: The external links are pointing to a Unicode directory to point to some official definition of these characters.

Answer (score 4):

STIX Two Math e.g. has the symbols:

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={"2987-"2988}]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range=\int]
\begin{document}
$ ⦇ a b ⦈ $
\end{document}
```

Cambria Math has it too. You can use the range option of unicode-math to mix it into your  font.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the third `\setmathfont`?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen to reset the math fontdimen to the one for latin modern math (but I'm not quite sure if it is still needed or if Will changed something here).

Comment: I copied STIX2Math.otf from https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/tree/master/OTF into my working directory but XeTeX complains about fontspec error: "font-not-found" ! The font "STIX2Math" cannot be found. What can I do? I tried \setmathfont{STIX2Math} to no avail.

Comment: Did you try my code?

Comment: Indeed, I got the same error message, I tried naming the font STIX2Math afterwards.

Comment: works fine for me (and uses the stix two math font already present in my tex system).

Comment: otfinfo: STIX2Math.otf: not an OpenType font (bad magic number) -- I guess this causes the problem